# Link to an specific Sheet/cell of a Sharepoint Excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have an Excel Workbook uploaded to my Sharepoint site.
I want to create an http link to that Excel but I want to point to an specific Sheet and cell, so the Excel opens at that position.

At the following link, I found how to reference a sheet:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197922

So, I built my http link like this:

```
<a href="http://SharepointSite/MyWorkBook.xls#Sheet2!D4">
```

However, the Excel opens on Sheet 1, cell A1. Not Sheet2, cell D4

Why is this not working? Is there any way to open an Excel that is uploaded at sharepoint in an specific Sheet/cell?

As additional info, the link is located inside a Sharepoint Webpage. So other options are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: The hyperlink to the KB article is now dead.

Answer (score 4):

I just spent most of the day trying to figure out a similar issue. I was trying to hyperlink an excel cell to a specific range in another excel document, both of which are on a sharepoint site. I finally figured it out. It looks like your code is good, but, if your sheet name has a space in it (e.g. Sheet Name), you must place a an apotrophe around it (e.g. 'Sheet Name'!D4). Otherwise, the link will insert a %20 to account for the space and break the link.

For anyone interested, my inserted hyperlink (from right-clicking, selecting the document and editing, is:
AHSS%20trial%20tracking.xlsx#'1180DP v.2.c.4'!B16:AB16

This links to the excel sheet named AHSS trial tracking, sheet 1180DP v2.c.4, range B16 to AB16

Answer (score 1):

This also applies to hyperlinks from cell to cell in the same document. I got around this from removing all the spaces (replaced them with underscores) in my document name & tab names.